# How to access div attributes (on click event) which is inside the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Below is my code.

Here whenever I click on song1 I need to get the respective id and attributes.

```
<div>
    <iframe id="songs" src="song.html">
        <div id="song1" class="sngs" name="song123">song1</div>
        <div id="song2" class="sngs" name="song122">song2</div>
        <div id="song3" class="sngs" name="song121">song3</div>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And this is what I am doing here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("iframe").click(function(){
        var currentsongName=$("iframe").contents().find("#"+this.id).getAttribute("name");
        console.log(currentsongName);
       playsong(currentsongName);
    });
});
```

but here this.id is coming something else.
so how can I get the id and its attribute of the div which I clicked on?

Comment: `'#' + $(this).prop('id')`. Also, `getAttribute()` is a native method, use jQuery equivalent `.attr()` instead.

Comment: @Teemu `this.id` is fine

Comment: @AmitJoki and even better

Comment: @AmitJoki I thought I've added a question mark to the end of that example, looks like I haven't. Anyway, though you're right, `this.id` should do, but OP states: "... here this.id is coming something else." Or are they just confused because of `getAttribute` causes an error?

Comment: Your basic problem is, that clicks are not bubbling to the parent page, when clicking on an element within an iframe. Only clicks on the border (if visible) of the iframe will trigger click event.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve native element by using an index

```
var currentsongName=$("iframe").contents().find("#"+this.id)[0].getAttribute("name");
```

or use jQuery equivalent of `attr()`

```
var currentsongName=$("iframe").contents().find("#"+this.id).attr("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the `iframe` is showing some content on the same server and same port than the one hosting jQuery script (container), and then you can access iframe thru its document object:

```
$($('iframe')[0].document, 'div.sngs').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: If the iframe is not from the same domain or port, by default you cannot access its content. see http://jsfiddle.net/rv8r74ac/

Comment: more explanation there http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a name TAG... add it or work with `id` instead.

```
$('iframe div.sngs').click(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr("id"));
     //now play song with id... 
});
```